# N-dimensional Hypercubes coloring

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

How many ways 3-cube vertices can be coloring using 10 color, vertices which have relation is not able to have same color.

I would also appreciate anyone who show the solution for finding total ways problems in order to color the graphs with more color than chromatic number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing the answer of Casteels, this can be done with Maple. The Maple code $$with(GraphTheory): with(SpecialGraphs):G := PrismGraph(4): $$ $$ChromaticPolynomial(G, t); eval(\%, t = 10); $$ outputs $$ t \left( t-1 \right)  \left( {t}^{6}-11\,{t}^{5}+55\,{t}^{4}-159\,{t}^
{3}+282\,{t}^{2}-290\,t+133 \right)
 $$ and $28478970. $
See [PrismGraph](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GraphTheory/SpecialGraphs/PrismGraph) and [ChromaticPolynomial](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GraphTheory/TuttePolynomial) for info.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) $P_G(x)$ is such that $P_G(k)$ is equal to the number of ways of properly coloring the vertices of $G$ using $k$ colors. So you want to calculate that for $G=$"$3$-cube" and plug in $k=10$.