# Chromatic polynomial of the (hyper-)cube graph $Q_3$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How can one compute the chromatic polynomial of the (hyper-)cube graph $Q_3$?

Is it easy to compute? Can we use the fact $Q_3= Q_2 \times P_2$ (where $P_2$ is the "path graph" with two vertices)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chromatic polynomial of the [cube graph $Q_3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) is $$x (x-1) (x^6-11 x^5+55 x^4-159 x^3+282 x^2-290 x+133)$$ found computationally ([Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=chromatic%20polynomial%20cube%20graph)).  I think it's unlikely there will be an easier way to compute this other than the usual [deletion-contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Deletion.E2.80.93contraction) methods.

See also:

- [N-dimensional Hypercubes coloring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599532/n-dimensional-hypercubes-coloring)